# a dcpo of categories has limits and compact categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

Hi,

Suppose you are given a dcpo of categories, where the functor is taken as the ordering relation.  This collection is a category too and it has limits, or perhaps cartesian products.  This comes from the shape of what the supremum looks like.  This dcpo might also be a topos.  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?
  Also, what are the compact elements?  That is to say, what universal properties do the compact elements have?

Comment: 'where the functor...' - which functor? And what is the question here. MO is not particularly suited to 'have any thoughts'-type questions.

Comment: I know some category theory, but I don't know all the jargon you're using ("dcpo" in particular).  Can you provide a bit more details?  (You will probably benefit from such an exercise as well: I find it very valuable to practice writing down definitions.)  Also, with @David Roberts, I'm not a fan of "does anyone have any thoughts" questions, although it looks like you do have some precise mathematical questions to ask, and those should be better highlighted.

Comment: Then again, The Google tells me that "dcpo" means "directed complete partial order".  I don't understand "where the functor is taken as the ordering relation" of course.

Comment: Probably you just mean that that the order relation is supposed to be realized by some prescribed functors?

Comment: My thoughts are "this question is not very clear" and "a dcpo cannot be a topos". Is this a random question, or did it actually occur in real work?

Comment: I am sorry for being so brief in the question.  This is a serious post.  I am not sure what the confusion is.  If I have an ordered structure constisting of a set of categories with an ordering relation then I have to describe that ordering relation.  So here is the ordering reltion: a functor.  How this has caused any confusion, I a not sure.  If this is still unclear then let me describe it differently.  Suppose I have a set of categories and also some set of funtors between the categries.  I may have ten categories and only one functor, say between cats A and B.  Ok.  So now suppose that th

Comment: Here is a more pointed form of this question. A dcpo can be seen as a category where there is only one map between any two objects.  Does this category have limits?

Comment: My understanding is that Ben is a physicist by training, has a degree under the supervision of Prakash Panangaden, and is interested both in diagrammatic methods for quantum physics (a la Coecke, for instance) and in domain-theoretic stuff. He has opened a number of discussions in the nForum around these themes. I don't think MO is a particularly good fit for his queries, as right now he is striving to get some basic intuitions about some things which could become interesting, but which for now have a strong discussion-y component, which as we know do not work well on MO. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your more pointed form of the question: if $P$ is a poset viewed as a category then the limit of a functor $F:I \to P$ is the same thing as $\inf \lbrace F(i) : i\in I \rbrace$ and the colimit is the same thing as $\sup \lbrace F(i) : i\in I\rbrace$. If I'm not mistaken a directed complete partial order is just a partially ordered set in which every directed subset has a supremum. So a dcpo doesn't have all limits or colimits in general.

Note that your example of taking a collection of categories with a preorder defined by the existence of functors between them doesn't amount to much without restricting the class of functors allowed (because of the existence of constant functors). On the other hand, if you use a restricted class of functors such that you do obtain a directed complete partial order then the first paragraph applies. In other words, knowing that it forms a dcpo doesn't provide you with limits although it does provide you with *some* colimits.

Perhaps I have misunderstood what you're getting at, but it is also possible that these elementary observations will be helpful.